# What is the Mathematical formula for CUMIPMT function of EXCEL(how it is calculated)?

Tags: excel, math

What is the Mathematical formula for CUMIPMT function of EXCEL(how it is calculated)? 
I want to calculate it mathematically. 
Please Help

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CUMIPMT-function-61067bb0-9016-427d-b95b-1a752af0e606

Comment: @MeldinXavier Hi, i have the Excel formula, i need the mathematical formula to calculate.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. Hint: Show effort and code. Your question is off topic as _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Comment: Also a duplicate of the easily found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42606570/excel-cumipmt-function-in-javascript

Answer (score 5):

The implementation of `CUMIPMT` in Excel is impossible for us to provide seeing as Excel is not open-source.

However numerous results show up in a Google search such as [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/ghalimi/4583240) in Javascript, [this other implementation](https://gist.github.com/fscottfoti/ef5b1785b22fc79ee8ba) also in Javascript, or [PHPExcel's implementation](https://github.com/ddeboer/phpexcel/blob/master/Classes/PHPExcel/Calculation/Financial.php) in PHP.

The closest result would probably be to look at Open Office's C++ implementation - thats very close or identical to Excel's implementation.

It's available in the OpenOffice repository on [Github](https://github.com/apache/openoffice/blob/c014b5f2b55cff8d4b0c952d5c16d62ecde09ca1/main/scaddins/source/analysis/financial.cxx)

```
double SAL_CALL AnalysisAddIn::getCumipmt( double fRate, sal_Int32 nNumPeriods, double fVal,
    sal_Int32 nStartPer, sal_Int32 nEndPer, sal_Int32 nPayType ) THROWDEF_RTE_IAE
{
    double fRmz, fZinsZ;

    if( nStartPer < 1 || nEndPer < nStartPer || fRate <= 0.0 || nEndPer > nNumPeriods  || nNumPeriods <= 0 ||
        fVal <= 0.0 || ( nPayType != 0 && nPayType != 1 ) )
        THROW_IAE;

    fRmz = GetRmz( fRate, nNumPeriods, fVal, 0.0, nPayType );

    fZinsZ = 0.0;

    sal_uInt32  nStart = sal_uInt32( nStartPer );
    sal_uInt32  nEnd = sal_uInt32( nEndPer );

    if( nStart == 1 )
    {
        if( nPayType <= 0 )
            fZinsZ = -fVal;

        nStart++;
    }

    for( sal_uInt32 i = nStart ; i <= nEnd ; i++ )
    {
        if( nPayType > 0 )
            fZinsZ += GetZw( fRate, double( i - 2 ), fRmz, fVal, 1 ) - fRmz;
        else
            fZinsZ += GetZw( fRate, double( i - 1 ), fRmz, fVal, 0 );
    }

    fZinsZ *= fRate;

    RETURN_FINITE( fZinsZ );
}
```

Comment: Or vote to close as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42606570/excel-cumipmt-function-in-javascript

Comment: If someone stumbles upon this, `GetRmz` and `GetZw` are the German equivalents of `PMT` and `FV` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

The complete OpenOffice formula converted to C# based on Daniel's suggestion:

```
/// <summary>
/// The Excel CUMIPMT function as implemented by OpenOffice.
/// https://github.com/apache/openoffice/blob/c014b5f2b55cff8d4b0c952d5c16d62ecde09ca1/main/scaddins/source/analysis/financial.cxx
/// </summary>
/// <param name="rate">rate as double (0.05 for 5%)</param>
/// <param name="numberOfPayments">nper</param>
/// <param name="presentValue">pv</param>
/// <param name="startPeriod">start_period</param>
/// <param name="endPeriod">end_period</param>
/// <param name="type">0 (for payment at the end of period) or 1 (for payment at the beginning of the period</param>
/// <returns>The cumulative interest paid on a loan between start period and end period.</returns>
public double? CumulativeInterestPaid(double rate, int numberOfPayments, double presentValue, int startPeriod, int endPeriod, int type)
{
    if (startPeriod < 1 || endPeriod < startPeriod || rate <= 0.0 || endPeriod > numberOfPayments || numberOfPayments <= 0 || presentValue <= 0.0 || (type != 0 && type != 1))
        return null;

    var fRmz = GetRmz(rate, numberOfPayments, presentValue, 0.0, type);
    var fZinsZ = 0.0;
    var nStart = startPeriod;
    var nEnd = endPeriod;

    if (nStart == 1)
    {
        if (type <= 0)
            fZinsZ = -presentValue;

        nStart++;
    }

    for (var i = nStart; i <= nEnd; i++)
    {
        if (type > 0)
            fZinsZ += GetZw(rate, i - 2, fRmz, presentValue, 1) - fRmz;
        else
            fZinsZ += GetZw(rate, i - 1, fRmz, presentValue, 0);
    }

    fZinsZ *= rate;

    return fZinsZ;
}

// https://github.com/apache/openoffice/blob/c014b5f2b55cff8d4b0c952d5c16d62ecde09ca1/main/scaddins/source/analysis/analysishelper.cxx
private double GetZw(double fZins, double fZzr, double fRmz, double fBw, int nF)
{
    double fZw;
    if (fZins == 0.0)
        fZw = fBw + fRmz * fZzr;
    else
    {
        var fTerm = Pow(1.0 + fZins, fZzr);
        if (nF > 0)
            fZw = fBw * fTerm + fRmz * (1.0 + fZins) * (fTerm - 1.0) / fZins;
        else
            fZw = fBw * fTerm + fRmz * (fTerm - 1.0) / fZins;
    }

    return -fZw;
}

// https://github.com/apache/openoffice/blob/c014b5f2b55cff8d4b0c952d5c16d62ecde09ca1/main/scaddins/source/analysis/analysishelper.cxx
private double GetRmz(double fZins, double fZzr, double fBw, double fZw, int nF)
{
    double fRmz;
    if (fZins == 0.0)
        fRmz = (fBw + fZw) / fZzr;
    else
    {
        var fTerm = Pow(1.0 + fZins, fZzr);
        if (nF > 0)
            fRmz = (fZw * fZins / (fTerm - 1.0) + fBw * fZins / (1.0 - 1.0 / fTerm)) / (1.0 + fZins);
        else
            fRmz = fZw * fZins / (fTerm - 1.0) + fBw * fZins / (1.0 - 1.0 / fTerm);
    }

    return -fRmz;
}
```

Comment: @sled mentions in a comment above that some of this may be German. If this is true and you speak German and you can decipher the variable names, please consider adding an answer "translating" them so this formula is more understandable to English developers.